# Radeon 4850 + Windows 7 64bit causing Blackouts/reboots while playing games

Tags: windows-7, cooling, amd-radeon, black-screen-of-death

Ever since I upgraded to windows 7 I can seem to play any games with my PC rebooting either straight away or after a few minutes of gaming, after reboot I get bios beeps for gfx card failure. The same PC worked fine with windows XP and vista.

The card is a Sapphire RADEON HD 4850 512MB. The games seem to run for longer if I turned down the graphic details and I set the fan to run at 100%. The card idles at 45 degrees C.

Iv updated directX to 11 and got the ati drivers to 10.7, and have even fitted an aftermarket heat sink to the graphics card, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tell us about the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the same card, and my issue was overheating. You say the card idles at 45c, but you may want to check what it runs at in a game. My card (the same exact card) was hitting 115c and my computer would shut off. If you alt-tab out of a game (or I used a second monitor) and have Catalyst Control Center up, check to see how hot your card is.

Now, that all said, mine idles at 75c because I didn't ever apply new thermal paste, but its just a thought, cause I know these cards run hot.